# How to Get Value of a GradientTexture2d

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

I am trying to make a procedurally generated island. I think I am almost finished with actual terrain generation part using OpenSimplex noise, only thing left is making it into a island surrounded by water. For that I am using a radial gradient Texture something that looks a bit like the picture below:

[image]

Only issue is I don't know how to get the Gradiant value. Preferably I am looking for a function that can return value from 0-1 based on the white and black areas of the map. I checked docs countless times and searched online, only thing I could find is `get_offset()` function but I am not sure how it works or if its what I am looking for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the pixels of a `Texture` from GDScript, you need to:

- Get a reference to the `Texture`. *`GradientTexture2d` is a `Texture`.*
- Get an `Image` of the `Texture` by calling the [`get_data`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_texture.html#class-texture-method-get-data) method.
- Call the [`lock`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_image.html#class-image-method-lock) method on the `Image`, so you can access the pixels. *Remember to call [`unlock`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_image.html#class-image-method-unlock) later.*
- Call either the [`get_pixel`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_image.html#class-image-method-get-pixel) method or the [`get_pixelv`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_image.html#class-image-method-get-pixelv) method on it, which gives you a `Color`.
- Call the [`unlock`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_image.html#class-image-method-unlock) method on the `image`.

On the other hand, if you want to work with the `Gradient` from GDScript, you need to:

- Call the [`interpolate`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_gradient.html?highlight=get_offset#class-gradient-method-interpolate) method on the `Gradient` which gives you a `Color`. *You can get the `Gradient` of a `GradientTexture2D` by reading the [`gradient`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_gradienttexture2d.html#class-gradienttexture2d-property-gradient) property.*

Either way, you would have a `Color`. Now, you probably want to read one of the channels of the `Color`. For that you can access the `r`, `g`, `b` and `a` properties of the `Color`. *If your image is gray scale, the `r`, `g`, `b` properties of the `Color`s you get from it should be equal, so either of them will do.*

Comment: iam kind of getting stuck on second and third step, do i have to create an Image object and then get attach my gradienttexture2d to it? thanks in advance!